# Swiftui published variable won't be updated in a view

Tags: swift, class, swiftui

I have a class named UserInfoViewModel which gets data from a URL in json format:

```
class UserInfoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users:[UserDetails] = []
    func getUsers(){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard let token = defaults.string(forKey: "jsonwebtoken") else {
            return
        }
        APIServices().userInfo(token: token) { (result) in
            switch result {
                case .success(let accounts):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.users = accounts.map(ZoneViewModel.init)
           print("Number of users in UserInfoViewModel = \(self.users.count)") //Working 
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I want to get the number of users in main view, Unfortunately Number of users in Main view prints 0  , while Number of users in UserInfoViewModel prints 4 which is the correct number.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject  private var usersList = UserInfoViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Image("lunchscreen").onAppear(perform: {
            download_Users() 
        })
    }
    
    
    func download_Users() {
            userList. getUsers()
            print("Number of users in Main view = \(usersList.users.count)") // Not working
     }
```

Is there any way to get the correct number of users?

Comment: Likely updated but not in the timing you want add a `Text` that displays the count to verify `onAppear` runs long before the `print` in the View Model. BTW tokens should never be stored in UserDefaults put then in Keychain.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, is there anyway to synchronize it ? or delaying the view until it gets updated ? Thanks agin for the Keychain recommendation.

Comment: Look into `async await` and completion handlers. You can also do something with `if else` by checking if the list is empty.

Comment: and also in `userList.getUsers()` is a async call so print statement will not be able to get the count of user because, your `userList.getUsers()` need to wait until network server respond. as explained by @loremipsum please have a look at `aync await`

Comment: If you use async/await and the .task modifier you don't even need an object